# Kafka Streams - Processor context commit

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

should we ever invoke `processorContext.commit()` in `Processor` implementation by ourselves? I mean invoking `commit` method inside scheduled `Punctuator` implementation or inside `process` method.

in which use cases should we do that, and do we need that at all? the question relates to both Kafka DSL with `transform()` and Processor API.

seems Kafka Streams handles it by itself, also invoking  `processorContext.commit()` does not guarantee that it will be done immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is ok to call `commit()` -- either from the Processor or from a Punctuation -- that's why this API is offered.

While Kafka Streams commits on a regular (configurable) interval, you can request intermediate commits when you use it. One example use case would be, that you usually do cheap computation, but sometimes you do something expensive and want to commit asap after this operation instead of waiting for the next commit interval (to reduce the likelihood of a failure after the expensive operation and the next commit interval). Another use case would be, if you set the commit interval to `MAX_VALUE` what effectively "disables" regular commits and to decide when to commit base on your business logic.

I guess, that calling `commit()` is not necessary for most use cases thought.

Comment: Are there any guarantees around manually calling commit though?

Comment: afaict from the code, a processor requesting commit will be processed at end of the current batch being processed by the StreamThread.

Comment: There are no guarantees -- it's treated as a request and it's an implementation detail, that may change without notice, how quickly the commit will happen. Your observation is correct: we check the flag after processing a certain amount of record (not after each record) in the current implementation. We do this, to keep runtime overhead low and to increase system throughput.

Comment: Agree with you on it being implementation detail not surfaced in the API. My concern was whether using commit without guarantees is a good pattern. A simpler kafka consumer might be better suited for a use case where an expensive computation is occuring per consumed message?

Comment: Guess it's a use-case dependent decision. The "problem" for KafkaStreams is, that `commit()` could be called even if the record is processed only partially (ie, not by all operator of a task) and thus, commit cannot be executed synchronously if requested. The earliest point would be, after the record is fully processed. And because there is already a delay, adding some more delay to get higher throughput seems to be a good trade-off.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks for explaining the rationale!

Answer (score 0):

For the use case I am batching certain number of record in processor process method and writing the batched records to File from process function if the batch size reaches like certain number(lets say 10).

Lets say we write one batch of records to file and system crashes at the point before commit happens (Since we cann't call explicit commits). Next time the stream starts and processor processes the records from the last committed offset. This means we could be writing some duplicate data to files. Is there anyway to avoid writing duplicate data??

Comment: Using a plain old kafka consumer could give you a smaller window of failure between the file write and commit.

Comment: Also you should consider writing this as a comment on the question, or a separate question in itself.

Comment: Thanks Vikas .. Suggestions taken. I didn't have permissions to add comment so posted it as answer. Didn't want to create new post as i felt this fits the context of the original question