# How to configure batch processing in Kafka Streams Binder?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Does Kafka Stream binder supports batch processing in springBoot ?
In the official documentation there is no property for that.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder

Comment: It is configurable in "Apache Kafka Binder" but couldn't find a way to do in "Kafka Stream Binder"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to process data in chunks/batches with kafka streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366623/how-to-process-data-in-chunks-batches-with-kafka-streams)

Comment: Thanks for your response Steephen. SO it means batch processing is not supported yet by Kafka Streams ?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7432

Comment: Yes. it does not.